# Devolver el control al programa cada ciclo de un for o foreach - C#, Windows Forms, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, bucle-for, foreach

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo **devolver el control al programa cada ciclo de un for o cada iteración de un foreach**, pero **sin salir del bucle o del iterado**r. Es decir, que el usuario pueda tocar botones de la pantalla a pesar de que el bucle esté realizándose.

Mi aplicación hace mover un punto, y lo que pretendo es que el usuario pueda pulsar botones como pausa, acelerar, etc. mientras que el punto se mueva y poder manejarlo.

He intentado imitar las **corrutinas** que se hacen en Unity, las cuales son bastante fáciles de implementar. Sin embargo, no sé por qué en Windows Forms no me funciona el mismo código que en Unity.

He probado varias formas con `IEnumerator` y `IEnumerable` aplicando el comando `yield return null;`, que es el que usan en Unity, pero no funciona. Os dejo el primer código que planteé (sin implementar ningún tipo de corrutina) y el último que he intentado, por si me pudierais ayudar:

```
private void MoverPunto(int X, int Y)
    {                       
        int pasos_h = 1;
         if (X < x) pasos_h = -1;

         for (; x != X; x+=pasos_h)
         {
             Planos.Refresh();
             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(velocidad);
         }

         int pasos_v = 1;
         if (Y < y) pasos_v = -1;

         for (; y!= Y; y+= pasos_v)
         {
             Planos.Refresh();
             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(velocidad);
         }

    }
```

Este es el primero que intenté, en el que consigo que se visualice el movimiento del punto hasta su destino final, pero no puedo pulsar ningún botón mientras se está moviendo.

```
    private  IEnumerable<string> GetListas(int H, int V)
        {
            int pasos_h = 1;
            if (H < x) pasos_h = -1;

            for (; x != H; x += pasos_h)
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            int pasos_v = 1;
            if (V < y) pasos_v = -1;

            for (; y != V; y += pasos_v)
            {
                yield return null;
            }
        }


        private void MoverPunto(int X, int Y) 
        {
            var listas = GetListas(X,Y);

            foreach(var item in listas)
            {
                Planos.Refresh();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(velocidad);

            }
      }
```

Y este es el último que he probado, en el que ocurre lo mismo que en el primero: **el punto sí se mueve, pero no puedo pulsar ningún botón**.

Para hacer la prueba y visualizar el código desarrollado,lo inicializo con la indicación: `MoverPunto(20, -20);` (las coordenadas que le he puesto son como ejemplo solamente).

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
Como menciono en los comentarios de abajo, he probado a ponerlo como una Task. Al primera vista debería funcionar bien, pero al ejecutar la aplicación me sale el siguiente error (pulsar en la imagen para visualizar mejor):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberias usar Task en tu metodo para que tus metodos no se ejecuten en el hilo principal y seguir usando yield para que te vaya devolviendo los numeros.

Comment: Lo que me parece extraño, es ver que tus metodos no tienen cierta logica, por ejemplo en MoverPunto recorres un foreach y esos items no los pasas a ningun lado. En GetListas, devolves null en todos los casos. Deberias dejar los metodos limpios, cual crees que deberia funcionar y ahi lo corregimos entre los que. sepan como ayudarte

Comment: Empecemos porque no tengo muchos conocimientos de programación... Edito mi pregunta y pongo el código inicial que planteé, por si se entiende mejor. Respecto a lo que me dices de usar una Task, me he estado informando y parece que lo puedo implementar, voy a probar a ver cómo lo puedo hacer. Muchas gracias por responder!

Comment: En realidad, no me interesa que me devuelva los números. Lo que me interesa es que la x y la y (minúsculas) tomen todos los valores hasta llegar a los que le indico con X e Y (mayúsculas) y con la función Planos.Refresh(); actualizar la pictureBox en la que se está produciendo el movimiento para que pueda ser visualizado.

Comment: He probado a poner el primer código que planteé como una Task y funciona correctamente PERO no me deja implementar la función Planos.Refresh();, me sale un error. Lo pongo en la pregunta como actualización.

Comment: Porque es un proceso que se ejecuta sobre el hilo principal. y tu tarea va por un hilo secundario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido solucionarlo.

Creo un Timer con un intervalo de 100ms por ejemplo, y cada vez que salta le asigno el comando `Planos.Refresh();` con lo que refrescamos la posición del punto cada 100ms.

```
    private void RefrescarPlanos_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Planos.Refresh(); 
    }
```

Y definimos la función MoverPunto con una Task dentro de él:

```
private void MoverPunto(int X, int Y)
    {

        var movimiento = new Task(() => 
          {
              int pasos_h = 1;
              if (X < x) pasos_h = -1;

              for (; x != X; x += pasos_h)
              {
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(velocidad);
              }

              int pasos_v = 1;
              if (Y < y) pasos_v = -1;

              for (; y != Y; y += pasos_v)
              {
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(velocidad);
              }
          }              
        );
        movimiento.Start();
    }
```

Así, conseguimos que el punto recorra todas las coordenadas situadas entre la posición actual del punto y el destino que le indicamos, mientras que también podemos pulsar los botones que queramos porque Task es una operación asíncrona.